# How can I create a hollow sphere with regularly spaced holes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

My latest attempt has involved a hexagon shape repeated with array modifiers.

[image: Hexagonal attempt with half sphere]

I then tried wrapping this over a sphere with the shrinkwrap modifier, but that didn't seem to work so well.

[image]

I couldn't get any better results by playing with the modifier offset or moving the two objects around.

Basically, I want to model something like this, with smaller holes:

[image: Ideal model]

Comment: one of the best variety of answers I have ever seen

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carvings-around-a-sphere

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67334/how-to-turn-my-honeycomb-pattern-into-the-sphere

Comment: Another technique in video I did in less than 1 minute. It sounds exactly like what you want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBrhTXSOBLY&t=0s I hope this will help you Antoine 3Da

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way is to Add an *Icosphere*, select all verts, bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>), extrude, and delete the extruded faces.
This will result in N-Gons but may be okay if you don't need to smooth.

[image: Select all Verts]

[image: Ctrl Shift B to Bevel]

[image: Extrude the faces in]

[image: Delete the extruded Faces]

Comment: according to his picture he want a mixture between pentagons and hexagons.

Comment: To get the shape looking more like the one in the image, try playing with _Ctrl + F > Wireframe_.

Comment: @User320 Actually, first the OP tries with only hexagons. I think he is content with both. :)

Comment: @MarkBTomlinson Sweet solution. However, you should just hit delete faces after the second image. Then add the solidify modifier. It gives you mesh thickness. This way it will have a solid inside.

Comment: @Gunslinger yep that would have been more like it, still interesting if you don't mind nGons.

Comment: Hi, this looks great! But I'm stuck at the first step. When I use the bevel command, it doesn't look anything like yours: http://imgur.com/h7x5dMT

Comment: Problem solved! I needed 'Shift+Ctrl+B', instead of 'Ctrl+B' to only bevel vertices. Sorry, I'm still really new to modelling

Comment: @Gunslinger, thanks for the tip. Deleting faces after the second step also meant that the extrusion closed the inside faces properly, which I needed for 3d printing

Answer (score 25):

Instead of the shrinkwrap, there's an older but more precise tool to turn verts into a sphere.

- Put the 3D-Cursor where the center of your sphere whould be
- Select all verts
- Hit <kbd>Space</kbd>, type 'to sphere' or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, select that tool and hit <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd> to make it completely spherical. Most subsurfed spheres aren't really precise, so this tool changes that.

Here's my approach to this:

[image]

## Making the cookie cutter

- Create a mesh that has faces where you want the holes to be (I).
- Parent a Cylinder to the Sphere and enable Duplifaces for the sphere (II)
- Scale the Cylinder to the desired width
- Select the sphere and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to make the duplis real.
- Select all Duplis and Shift-Select the middle one, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join them into one single mesh

## Making the sphere

- Make a sphere to your liking. I used an Icosphere with applied subsurf modifier and 'To Sphere. While in Editmode I gave it depth by duplicating it, scling it in and flipping the normals, so the boolean modifier will be happy.
- Put the Cylinder object right where your sphere is and scale it so the cylinders intersect with both inner and outer surface of the sphere. Save your file.
- Give the sphere a boolean modifier, set it to Difference and put the cylinder mesh in the *Object* field to perform the task.
- Hit *Apply*.
- Delete, hide or move the Cylinder mesh
- Give your sphere an *Edge Split* modifier and set the shading to smooth.

The advantage is that it works with irregular shapes too.

## Try this to get close to the example image

(Bevelling like Mark did is much faster. Do it like he suggested and skip to the bucky ball.)

Start with a level one icosphere

[image]

Subdivide it twice

[image]

Select one corner vert and use *Select* (or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) >> *Select Similar* >> *Amount of Adjacent Faces*

[image]

Dissolve the verts with <kbd>X</kbd> >> Dissolve Vertices.

[image]

Enter *Face Select Mode*.

Select one pentagon and this time use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> Select Similar* >> *Polygon Sides*.

Invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

[image]

Get rid of the excess faces with <kbd>X</kbd> >> *Limited Dissolve*

[image]

Select everything and hit the Smooth vertex button a few times. (This is the point to which you could jump if you followed Marks Tutorial. My approach is pre-vertex beveling)

In vertex select mode, subdivide two times. This extra topology is useful to get a round sphere.

[image]

Inset individual faces (<kbd>I</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>)

Delete the big faces with the help of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> select similar*.

[image]

Subdivide again. Select everything and use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> To Sphere* with factor of `1.0`

[image]

Extrude it four times and scale inwards each time.

[image]

Give it a subsurf modifier and enjoy the result.

[image]

Comment: Hm, too much work to delete, but the images of the question loaded after I finished the 'answer'. I'm not only starving, I also have only 64kbit internet. Sorry

Comment: on the other hand, if you use six sided cylinders...

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! It's great to see the difference between dupli-faces and dupli-verts, but I think I like the dupli-verts a little better

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I think I have something that will get you pretty much that same result. First create an icosphere and set the subdivide to 5.

[image: Settings for icosphere]

Then find a five sided pole and select it. Then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and select from the dropdown, "Amount of Adjacent Faces". You should have several isolated vertices selected throughout the mesh. The hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>numpad+</kbd> 4 times to expand your selection.

[image: vertices to delete]

Delete the selected vertices. You will notice several six sided shapes left. Select the interior vertices like this,

[image: Six sided selection]

and delete them until you have a mesh that looks like this.

[image: Final Mesh]

After this, just add a skin modifier and a subsurf modifier.

[image: Modifiers]

You should have something that by now, looks a bit like this.

[image: Final Result]

If the "Tubes" are a bit large, you have to select all vertices in the mesh and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and "scale" the vertices to your liking. After you are happy with the result, just apply the skin modifier. I hope this works how you want it to.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a flexible approach using dupliverts and a boolean modifier to create patterned circular holes in any object:

1. Add Ico sphere object
   [image]
2. Add Cylinder object
   [image]
3. Rotate Cylinder 90 degrees on X axis, apply Rotation
   [image]
4. Parent Cylinder to Ico sphere
   [image]
5. In the Properties Object tab for the Ico sphere, select Duplication-> Verts and check Rotation. After that, apply Make Duplicates Real
   [image]
6. Delete Ico sphere and original Cylinder, Join the remaining cylinders in to one object[image]
7. Add the target sphere you want to poke holes in (for this example, a UV sphere), then add a Boolean modifier for the new sphere, using Difference based on the new Cylinder object created
   [image]
8. Apply the modifier, delete the new Cylinder object
   [image]

Comment: which is exactly what I proposed yesterday (:

Comment: Oh cool, that's awesome! That's similar to my first attempt, which involved cylinders, array modifier + rotation, and the boolean modifier. But this is pretty much exactly what I wanted. The answer above had a mix of pentagons and hexagons, but this means I can cut out regular holes in any shape.

Answer (score 6):

[image: steps]

I suppose I'll add one as well,

**A)** Add any shape you like.

**B)** Use a variation of **Extrude,** accessed with (<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>) and select **Edges Only**.  Now drag out the newly created edges far enough away from the original so that they do not overlap.

**C)** Select the old geometry in **Wireframe** mode and use (<kbd>x</kbd>) then (<kbd>e</kbd>) to delete the edges.  Now select the points which remain and this time use (<kbd>x</kbd>) then (<kbd>d</kbd>) to delete those points.

**D)** Now what you are left with is a wireframe of the original model.

**E)** Add a **Skin** modifier.

**F)** Use (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>) to scale the weight of each point. This tool will puff out, or contract, the geometry that this modifier creates.

**G)** Apply the **Skin** modifier and then add a **Subdivision Surface** modifier.

Comment: Steps B and C are just needlessly complicated way of doing x -> only faces