# How to turn my honeycomb pattern into the sphere?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to bender and followed some tutorials. After following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gipp5Lh_aw8) one I'm trying to make the pattern I have into a ball. I can make the pattern follow a path, so it's probably not that hard to make it follow a sphere. However I'm stuck and I don't know if it's possible. Hope somebody can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This video is half an hour long and doesn't explain what you are trying to do, so you need to add images of what you are doing and what exactly is the problem. Also, it can be deleted later on and then the question will be meaningless.

Comment: @KMFrits I think I understand waht you mean but no, it's not as simple as a curve modifier! If you can use a texture, you could probably search some other question like http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=sphere+map. If you really need a spherical honeycomb mesh, it's more difficult, probably... It could be constructed by a python script, perhaps?

Comment: The nearest shape I can think of is an ICO sphere... but it has 5 and 6 sided faces... see this (3dsmax) video for reference https://youtu.be/9AOUTy2BlAk?t=34

Comment: You can deform a sphere from plane by using 2 curves, 180 degree one and 360 degree one. The hard part is trying to make it contiguous or without seams. This approach would make the shape infinitely stretched near the polar areas. You can't build a sphere out of regular hexagons because that would constitute a flat shape (6*60 = 360 degrees). That's why soccer balls have the pentagons. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to make?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I can go on from here! I'm trying to create an image, that makes it seem like a honeycomb planet. I've used some tips from you guys and got what I needed for this graphic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may achieve it ***beveling*** the ***Ico Sphere (Percent mode)*** and ***inseting*** the faces.
[image]

Add an ***Ico Sphere*** and subdivide it (in my case I've made 3 subdivisions).
[image]

Select the whole mesh in *Edit Mode* with <kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel it. Use the <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> to reduce segments to 1. Press <kbd>M</kbd> twice to enable the *Percent* mode and scale hexagons to lay as close to each other as possible. Next *remove doubles* with <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*. Increase the *Merge Distance* value if needed.

***NOTE:*** You can achieve similar effect using the ***Bevel Modifier***, but geometry may be more dense then.
[image]

Now add a *Subsurf Modifier* with some subdivisions and smooth the object in the *Tool Shelf's* (<kbd>T</kbd>) *Edit* panel. With the whole mesh selected press <kbd>I</kbd> twice to *inset individual faces*, then scale the faces inwards to create the holes.
[image]

Finally with the whole mesh selected (<kbd>A</kbd>) press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to crease the edges. Play with the *Mean Crease* value in the *Transform* panel of *Properties Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>) to adjust its strenght as you like. 
[image]

***FINAL NOTE:*** The model has pentagons as @kheetor warned about, but they're not much noticable.
[image]

Comment: Just found a related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-can-i-create-a-hollow-sphere-with-regularly-spaced-holes Maybe helpful for you.

Answer (score 9):

Really like Paul's solution, but just to give another option. With the understanding that a perfect honeycomb sphere is theoretically impossible, and just going for a look here. This option does require the [Tissue Add-on](http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue).

[image]

- Create a hexagon from a 6 sided circle and give it some thickness.
- Add a cube and sub-divide it smooth.
- Select the hexagon, then the 'smooth' cube and *Tessalate*
- Choose Quad and adjust scale if you    like..

You can always adjust the original mesh and update the generated.

[image: Tissue]

**Note:** Do this is Top view for predictable results.

Just for reference, these were the settings...

[image]

Update: Tried the same procedure again but this time with a different connector...

[image]