# Creating array of holes

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to model a "vent" like on an air conditioner and I am familiar with the BOOLEAN tool... So I know I can make a slab of metal out of a BOX and punch a hole in it using the BOOLEAN tool the make the grates on the vent. But here's the thing....

I need to make them in a 9 x 34 (h x v) pattern, and I'm trying to figure out how to do this without literally using the BOOLEAN tool 102 times and having to place them exactly where they need to go...

There has to be a way to automate this...  I've heard of the ARRAY MODIFIER.   Would using the ARRAY MODIFIER with the BOOLEAN tool be the way to approach this? Do I need to write a script in PYTHON?

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have an idea of what you want... what are you looking for here that you can't get by simply trying your hypothesis?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carvings-holes-around-a-sphere and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/how-to-create-a-circular-shaped-grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-can-i-create-a-hollow-sphere-with-regularly-spaced-holes/

Answer (score 1):

Yup thats what I would do. I'd apply the array modifier to your vent cutouts, then extrude them and add a boolean modifier.

1) Create the shape of your vents and apply a array modifier

[image]

2) You can adjust the distance between the shapes and add more of them here

[image]

Then just apply the array then boolean it to your vent.