# How to make a primitive cylinder form a regular punctured sphere?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, color

I would like to make a shape like the one shown in the screenshot below. I've looked at other questions, yet they were made in the previous version of Blender. The version I am currently using is 2.91, can you tell me what version this model was made in? Additionally, I also wonder how to make a primitive cylinder show three colors like the one shown in the other screenshot below.

[image]

Please be aware that the sphere is a UVSphere and not an icosphere. So all linked answers won't work with UVSphere!
[image]

[How can I create a hollow sphere with regularly spaced holes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-can-i-create-a-hollow-sphere-with-regularly-spaced-holes) (old version)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the other questions (for older versions)? The process might be translatable, but I can't tell because I don't know what they did.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE. Please ask only one question. And of course you can open as many questions as you like.

Comment: Ahh, I was just in the middle of it. Dealing with the poles on a UV Sphere is a bit of an extra. I'll finish the answer.. I may post it over there.

Comment: @RobinBetts: a wonder happened. They reopened it. So just DO IT! ;)

Comment: @Chris.. I think we'd better delete some of this commentary clutter ... It's [done OK](https://imgur.com/SXBGYoP).. but there are mores steps than I thought, to get a clean result.

Comment: @RobinBetts: Looks GREAT!!!! Love it! i tried too...but didn't make it :(

Comment: ok...deleted the commentary clutter...just for you! 

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways of making the perforated sphere; this tries to pick one that has a smaller number of necessary steps.. some of these are optional. The topology isn't the best, but it doesn't affect the result.

[image]

- For a smooth result, you may want to delete pole vertices, and fill the hole with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > Grid fill; maybe <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide some latitudes to make faces squarer. Keep an intact, highly subdivided version of the sphere handy, for moves like this. You can always *Shrinkwrap*, and apply the modifier, to that, to restore the spherical shape.
- <kbd>I</kbd> (With <kbd>I</kbd> for 'Individual',)Inset the faces that will be holes
- Face Menu > Subdivide the new faces.

[image]

- Now, if you hit <kbd>F</kbd>, the edges will be dissolved, but the extra vertices remain
- You can use the shipped add-on *Loop Tools > Circle*, to make them round, with *Fit Inside*, if you want your holes to be scaled to the faces, or to a *Radius*, if you want them all the same size.
- Even then, you might want to adjust the sizes. Set your Transform Orientation to 'Normal', and your Pivot to 'Individual Origins', and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to change their size, or simply repeat the Loop-Tools operation, with a radius set.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Select Similar, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> select next in sequence, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> / <kbd>Numpad -</kbd>, expand / contract selection, will help you pick out the faces for treatment. Sometimes you have to <kbd>H</kbd> hide sections of the mesh you're not interested in.

[image]

- You can then <kbd>I</kbd> inset your holes a fraction before deleting them,
- and give everything a Solidify and Subdiv. modifier.

The surface seems to be of reasonable quality.. with other approaches, you have always got the intact sphere available to *Shrinkwrap* to, or to use *Data Transfer* to transfer Normals to the final result.

The 'Spike' version starts the same way..

[image]

- But instead of deleting the holes, you delete the sphere. Give the Object 2 material slots. As you inset and extrude the various sections, assign the faces to the appropriate slots as you go along, while the faces are still selected by the operations.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Extrude the faces inward, along their normals.
- The third frame show the rings of faces selected, ready to be assigned the second material slot.

[image]

Comment: Oh my god! Your knowledge is amazing!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, there is a question about this. I even got rid of the triangular parts above and below the UV sphere. But it's not doing the grid fill. What am I supposed to do with this?

Comment: Hi @YunJungShin If you choose to delete the poles, you should be left with round holes. Select the perimeter edges of those holes, and Ctrl-F, Face menu > Grid Fill, One perimeter at a time.